# Are there Badges for all Tags?

Tags: support, tags, badges

I just received my first "Tag" Badge (Microsoft-Excel, yeah!).  When I looked into the [Tags that had badges](https://superuser.com/badges?tab=tags), I didn't notice any particular system for which Tags had Badges (at any level).

Are these Badges automatically created by the system once someone meets the minimum criteria (e.g. 100 upvotes and 20 answers for Bronze) for a particular tag? Or are these pre-set and only the current Badges will be awarded? I couldn't find anything in the FAQ or on Meta that addresses them.

Comment: That's what I get for checking the site in Mobile, the Legend was cut-off and I missed the obvious answer. @Oliver Salzburg thanks for editing the link in, when I followed it, I found what I previously had missed.

Comment: You're welcome, I just wanted to add the link for reference though :)

Comment: More information on tag badges: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68395#68395

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, there are badges for any tag where at least one person has met that criteria. MOST of my badges on SU are random tag badges

Comment: Not completely true, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68395#68395): Tags must qualify for a badge by being actually used enough.